# Calcular diferença de valor da mesma coluna após soma com condição

Tags: mysql

Queria calcular o saldo de um extrato, visto que tenho campos como `extrato_tipo` e `extrato_valor`, sendo que o `extrato_tipo` utilizo para poder definir se o extrato é de entrada ou saída.

**Exemplo**

```
extrato_id | extrato_tipo | extrato_data | extrato_valor

   1       |     e        | 2021-05-09   | 500.00 
   2       |     s        | 2021-05-09   | 400.00
   3       |     e        | 2021-05-09   | 500.00  
   4       |     s        | 2021-05-09   | 400.00
```

Onde: e = entrada e s = saida

Se eu somar todas as entradas e diminuir pela soma das saídas, tem que dar 200 reais.
Estou em dificuldade em montar essa query.

Comment: Você consegue obter a soma de toda as entradas e a soma de todas as saídas?

Comment: consegui resolver

Comment: pq eu tinha montado uma outra query, antes do ricardo responder, marque a dele como solução!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer isso usando um `CASE WHEN` dentro do `SUM`, retornando  "extrato_valor" quando "extrato_tipo" for igual a 'e' e "extrato_valor * -1" caso contrário, o que vai fazer somar e subtrair:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN extrato_tipo = 'e' THEN extrato_valor 
           ELSE (extrato_valor * -1) END) 
 FROM  nome-da-tabela;
```

Pode ver a query funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/174b15/3

Comment: eu coloquei a forma que eu encontrei como solução, falando de desempenho, qual forma é melhor? Acredito que a sua, a query está mais limpa

Comment: eu não vi a sua solução, mas se a tabela tiver poucos dados não deve ser problema nenhuma query, agora se a tabela tiver muitos dados, a melhor alternativa seria somar as entradas e as saídas em duas subqueries separadas, e talvez seja necessário um index em "extrato_tipo", pois precisa de um where nesse campo (ou o case), mas tudo isso só com dados mesmo para ter certeza :)

Comment: Eu tinha usado subquery da forma original